next-swagger-doc Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
Currently, I am trying to implement Swagger UI for my Next.JS project with APIs. However, the module is returning this error: (Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object).
The following is one of my swagger notation just in case if this is the problem.
/**

* @swagger
* /api/user/users:
*   get:
*     summary: Get users for a given semester and year or the active semester
*     description: Retrieves all users for a specified semester and year or the active semester if no semester and year are provided.
*     parameters:
*       - in: query
*         name: semester
*         schema:
*           type: string
*         required: false
*         description: The semester to fetch users for (1 or 2).
*       - in: query
*         name: year
*         schema:
*           type: string
*         required: false
*         description: The year to fetch users for (e.g., '2023').
*     responses:
*       200:
*         description: A list of users
*         content:
*           application/json:
*             schema:
*               type: array
*               items:
*                 type: object
*                 properties:
*                   id:
*                     type: string
*                   // Add other user properties here
*       400:
*         description: Invalid semester or year
*       404:
*         description: No active semester found
*       405:
*         description: Method not allowed
*       500:
*         description: Error fetching users
*/

I have followed step by step from the Github page, but it is still causing that. I also have tried with swagger-jsdoc, but it seems to be the same problem, suggesting that the problem is originating from swagger-jsdoc module.
Github Page

I think get: needs more indentation: *   get:. Not sure if that's what causes the issue though.

Sorry, that was just my typo. It was indented correctly in the real program.

Not an answer, just a comment:
The snippet you posted is a mix of JavaDoc and OpenAPI; that cannot be readily copy-pasted for further examination.
If it helps, consider changing your snippet to proper OpenAPI yaml syntax:
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: SO-78693222
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /api/user/users:
    get:
      summary: Get users for a given semester and year or the active semester
      description: Retrieves all users for a specified semester and year or the active semester if no semester and year are provided.
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: semester
          schema:
            type: string
          required: false
          description: The semester to fetch users for (1 or 2).
        - in: query
          name: year
          schema:
            type: string
          required: false
          description: The year to fetch users for (e.g., '2023').
      responses:
        200:
          description: A list of users
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    id:
                      type: string
        400:
          description: Invalid semester or year
        404:
          description: No active semester found
        405:
          description: Method not allowed
        500:
          description: Error fetching users

(this can be copy-pasted into https://editor.swagger.io/)
(Note I also removed // Add other user properties here from your snippet, because that is not proper OpenAPI yaml either)
As it turns out, this OpenAPI spec here is valid according to https://editor.swagger.io/; so maybe your problem is caused elsewhere?
